# Prompt before reload/exit only if there is text entered

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am looking to prompt the user before they close or reload my app, built using HTML/JS/CSS.

After searching around, I tinkered with some code and got the following:

```
$('input:not(#opCodeEntry),textarea').one('change',function() {
    $('body').attr('onbeforeunload',"return 'Leaving this page will cause any unsaved data to be lost.';");
});
```

So with the exception of the #opCodeEntry (it's a type of login box and I don't care if that has changes or not), it seemed to work too well... It always prompts me when reloading/closing the window.

So here was attempt number two:

```
$('input:not(#opCodeEntry),textarea').one('change',function() {
    if ( $('input:not(#opCodeEntry),textarea').val() != "" ) {
        $('body').attr('onbeforeunload',"return 'Leaving this page will cause any unsaved data to be lost.';");
    } else {
        $('body').attr('onbeforeunload',"");
    }

});
```

Here's where things get confusing for me: I entered the following line in the console:

```
$('input:not(#opCodeEntry),textarea').val() != ""
```

And before logging in, I get false, and I can reload without a prompt.
After logging in, I get true, but I can still reload without a prompt.
If I edit a text box (I apparently have to tab away afterwards for it to be considered a change), it remains true, but then I get prompted.
If I edit a text box, tab away, then clear the contents of the text box, and then tab away again, I get true, and I get prompted.

What I want to happen is to only prompt the user if there is text in the text box.  If there isn't, either because they didn't do anything or because they erased it all (or cleared the form), I want to just reload/close.  Not sure why it's broken, and maybe I'm tired, but I can't figure out the flow, and what I did wrong.

Are there workarounds for custom event handling for a reload/exit event (via reload, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, or whatever)?

Comment: try `on` instead of `one`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
 $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    if ( $('input:not(#opCodeEntry),textarea').val() != "" ) {
        return 'Leaving this page will cause any unsaved data to be lost.';
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, .on() is exhibiting the same behavior as .one(); If I change any text, even if I delete it all, it will prompt me...

Comment: Hey, Anthony. Note that he’s attaching the event listener to the window object, not the document. That’s the important part. Further, note that he’s not assigning a function to an “onbeforeunload” property of the window, but instead he’s calling the “.on()” method, to attach an event listener the normal way. I’m not 100% sure, but I believe event handlers referenced on html element is properties are only invoked when the page first loads, so setting the “onbeforeunload” won’t help you. I repeat: $(window).on(‘beforeunload’,(guchi, stuff)=>0/0)

Comment: I'm going to take a look on Monday when I can get to the code, and I'll take another jab at it.  Knowing me, I think I only changed it to .on() and not .one() because I'm 'highly intelligent' (sarcasm, haha), and I'll do a once over and see if I can't get it to work!

Comment: I even tried copying and pasting the answer into the code, clearing out my old code, and it's not behaving properly.  I even tried being more specific regarding input, forgetting I have radio and checkbox type inputs, and even then, when excluding anything that has a value attribute I can't seem to get it to play nice.

I'm going to most likely settle for just alerting the user to be EXTRA CAREFUL before reloading or exiting the app.